# again traverse the array in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array of 5 elements:-

```
var a=[1,2,3,4,5];
```

and a variable which will have some integer value from firebase. So, what I want is that when this value is less than the length of array then it should print the value of array at that index i.e.

```
    int valueFromFireBase=3;
    print(a[valueFromFireBase]);
    //Result should be 4
```

and when it is greater than the length of array then it should again traverse the array i.e.
if value is 6 then it should print 1.

The code i have tried is :-

```
int val=0;
  var a=[1,2,3,4,5,6];
  int valueFromFireBase=7;
  if(valueFromFireBase>=a.length)
  {
    int divident=valueFromFireBase%a.length;
    valueFromFireBase-=divident;
    val=a[valueFromFireBase];
  }
  else
  {
    val=a[valueFromFireBase];
  }
  print(val);
```

But this code is not working when valueFromFireBase is equal to the array length.

Comment: Are you sure about if firebase value is `6` you want the code to return `1`? 6 would be `2` in your example since `0` is also a valid index value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a modulo operator:

```dart
val = a[valueFromFireBase % a.length];
```

Note that arrays indexes are 0-based so if `valueFromFireBase == 7` you'll get the 8th element.

```dart
void main() {
  final a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  final valueFromFireBase = 7;

  int val = a[valueFromFireBase % a.length];
  print(val);
}
```

https://dartpad.dev/59c42e89348e45ca433bcab1e3930572?null_safety=true

Modulo docs: https://api.dart.dev/be/138352/dart-core/double/operator_modulo.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do simply like this:

```
int val=0;
  var a=[1,2,3,4,5,6];
  int valueFromFireBase=7;
  if(valueFromFireBase>=a.length)
  {
    val=a[valueFromFireBase % a.length];
  }
  else
  {
    val=a[valueFromFireBase];
  }
  print(val);
```